# Depth or 3D camera for machine vision or robotic application in the range 0.2 meter to 5 meter?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, vision

I have found two depth/3d camera.

1. [Intel SR300](http://intel.com/realsense)
2. [Zed camera](https://www.stereolabs.com/)

Zed camera gives a map at a range 0.7 meter to 20 meter. But my application needs minimum range for depth approx 0.2 meter.

Intel SR300 works for range 0.2 meter to 1.5 meter. 1.5 meter is not enough.

Is there any alternative which work for a range 0.2 meter to 5 meter or more @ 30 fps for depth image ? 
SKD should be availabe for linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2017, there is no single device capable of doing both near and far depth.

You may need to wait for the Intel RealSense R400 Series which seems to have both.
Please note that Intel uses stereoscopic IR to capture the 3D in their recent devices which may give shaky results.

[image: Intel R400]

Answer (score 0):

Tara stereo camera might be suitable to your needs. Depth ranges from 50cm to 300cm. 
Linux OS supported. TARA SDK (OpenCV) Application includes Face Detection, Point Cloud, TaraDepthViewer, etc.

QVGA    (2*320) x 240   60 fps

Answer (score 0):

ZED Mini would now also be an option. Depth range from 10 cm to 12 m https://www.stereolabs.com/zed-mini/

The camera comes with a nice SDK including Visual Odometry, Pointcloud generation etc.